# Laravel 5.5 Eloquent not putting quote marks around a search string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am trying to pass a value from the URL to a controller to get data with the string from the URL, here is the route that passes the data to the controller this is working fine, and the correct values are making it to the controller

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('test/{name}', 'EmployeeController@getAllEmployees');
```

I have tried $name, "$name" , '$name' , '%' . $name . '%' , '%$name%'

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllEmployees($name)
    {
        $model = Employee::where('Name', 'LIKE',  $name)->get();
        return $model->tojson();
    }
}
```

Here is the error, as you can see the value doesn't have any quote marks around it which is what sqlsrv is tripping up with when running the query

```
"SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Tabel_Name'. (SQL: select * from [Tabel_Name] where [Name] LIKE test)",
```

what am i doing wrong?

Laravel 5.5
sqlsrv 
php 7.0

Comment: Show us your Employee model

Comment: It doesn't need to. Eloquent uses parameter binding, so it bypasses the need to quote variables.

Comment: The error is coming from the fact that `Tabel_Name` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't care about quotes because error comes from table and not from missing quotes (Laravel uses PDO to bind query parameters). The problem here is probably missing table in database.

So make sure you have already run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

or if you haven't created such table, you should create new migration and then run this command to create table in database

Comment: The error message should still accurately represent the query having the issue for troubleshooting. The fact that it doesn't is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your table name is in fault. Laravel uses a convention if your table name is **posts** then your model name should be **Post** other you will have to define table name in the model itself.What is your Model name and table name?